# comparing Scala lists with Java lists

Tags: java, list, scala, comparison, equality

How can I compare a Scala list with a Java list?

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
res1: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

scala> res0 == res1
res2: Boolean = false
```

Is there some static helper method for comparison that accepts both Scala lists and Java lists? Or is there a kind of "lazy wrapper" over both sorts of lists which I can then directly compare via `==`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

... or use `sameElements`.

```
scala> import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.JavaConversions._

scala> res0.sameElements(res1)            
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Note that this also causes the Java collection to be wrapped in a Scala Buffer (shown when using `-Xprint:typer`). This is the code actually executed: `res0.sameElements(asScalaBuffer(res1))`

Comment: I should probably clarify that my answer used to be a reply to somebody else's answer, in which he said you could both do the implicit conversion to a Scala collection and then compare, or compare every element one by one. He then went on to show how you can do that: have a method that compares every element. I just wanted to say that there is an easier way to compare every element for equality. Hence the "... or use `sameElements`. The answer to which I responded has been removed after that.

Comment: So I think the other answer is actually the better answer. Let me vote for that.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `JavaConverters` for this:

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> res0 == res1.asScala
res2: Boolean = true
```

Note that the `asScala` only returns a view on the original `List`, see documentation of `asScalaBufferConverter` in [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$) documentation.